# Grabbing specific char from CharArray

Tags: c#

I have this CharArray:

```
char[] letters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm123456789".ToCharArray();
```

I would like to know how I would grab a specific letter from this array. For example, lets say I have

```
int lengthMin = 1;
int lengthMax = 5;
```

Following the code above, how would I get  the first, second, third, fourth and fifth letters from the CharArray? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "first, second, fourth and fifth" What about the third?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Whoops, fixed that :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

```
var specificLetters = letters
    .Skip(lengthMin - 1)
    .Take(lengthMax - lengthMin + 1)
    .ToArray();
```

And, unlike @ecanmcdonnal's solution, you don't have to worry about the range, as long as they are not negative.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a for loop with lengthmax as the upper limit and length min as the lower. You should also do a couple checks though to make sure lengthmin is >= 0 and lengthmax is <= letters.length. I'm excluding that here for the sake of a concise example.

```
List<char> chars = new List<char>();

for (int i = lengthMin; i < lengthMax; i++)
{
    chars.Add(letters[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use array copying

```
var target = new char[lengthMax - lengthMin + 1];
Array.Copy(letters , lengthMin  , target , 0, lengthMax );
```

Comment: `Array.Copy` expects a 0-indexed `sourceIndex`, which `lengthMin` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 1 liner:

```
var result = letters.Take(--lengthMax)
                    .Skip(--lengthMin);
```